# Directions request failed due to REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: javascript

My map will display but this error will show up on my webpage - "Directions request failed due to REQUEST_DENIED"

http://foothillertech.com/student/globalit/2017/04_34/assets/tinker/Scraper/munchiez.php

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Directions service</title>

<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the 
  div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="floating-panel">
<b>Start: </b>
<select id="start">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>

<b>End: </b>

<select id="end">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</script>
```

Here is where the problem with the API is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud Platform select your project go to API Key edit and Select Directions API

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API does not allow un-authenticated requests and requires the use of an API key.

If you open your JavaScript Console, you will see these entries:

> Directions Service: This service requires an API key.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
>
> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
>
> Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required